# What property describes the non-decomposability nature of "min"?

Tags: functions

We know that sum can be incrementally adjusted. For example, if `c = a + b` and `a` changes to `a'`, then `c = c + (a' - a)` reflects the change.

However, if `c = min(a, b)` and if `a` changes to `a'`, then the change in `c` is not trivial. If `a' < c`, then `c = a'`. But if `a' > c`, then we need to re-evaluate `min(a', b)` to correctly reflect the change. The cost of re-evaluation increases with the number of variables in `min` function.

In layman's terms, `min` appears non-decomposable while `sum` appears decomposable. Is there a formal mathematical property that describes such functions like `min`?

Also, are there other functions like `min`/`max` that follow the same property?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Perhaps you mean that the sum in multilinear and min is not.

Comment: Google "multilinear" then come back here if you have more questions.